# sharepoint 2010 shared gantt chart - out of the box functionality

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, web-part, gantt-view

we're looking to share a task list with an associated gantt chart view across multiple sites within the same site collection. We have tried saving the web part and included data within share point designer, and then uploaded this web part on an alternative site, only to be presented with a generic share point error

(this method works when no gantt chart view is attached)

have tried googling etc, but unfortunately cannot find any answers..

any help or advice would be appreciated as we've been looking at this for some time now, This is purely out of the box technology

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind is that the destination sites don't have the features enabled to support Gantt charts. I don't know exactly which feature it is (possibly the Team Collaboration Lists feature?), but you could compare the activated features of the working site to the destination site. Beyond that, the only thing I can think of is permissions.

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, the sites have all the features required enabled, as its possible to create lists on those other sites with a gantt chart. Its strange, as it works fine sharing a list with no gantt chart. Im wondering if this is a bug with SharePoint?

Comment: What method are you using to transfer this list? Is it simply a list + content, or is it actually a web part embedded in a page?

Comment: hi, its literally open share point designer, and save the list as a web part selecting includ data. Then on a web part page it is required on, upload the web part, and include it on the page. With no Gantt chart, it works a dream. With a Gantt chart, SharePoint falls over on the page it has been included on.

Comment: Saving a web part and uploading to a different site seems to work for list views but can cause corruption in the source list.  I have not tried it with Gantt Charts but have you tried creating a new source in SPD in the target site and then create a view based on that?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, could you explain more about creating a new source? basically what we are trying to achieve is we have a customer request site, within this site, managers can assign requests to users with a gantt chart. Each team has their own sub site. We would like this gantt chart view to be shared and displayed on these sub sites, so for instance, i could log into my teams site, and see which requests have been assigned to me.

Comment: You can create a new data source in a site based on a list in a different site.  Once you have that new data source then you may be able to create your Gantt Chart from that.  If not, then could you just have a link to the Gantt Chart from each sub-site which links back to the site with the list?

Comment: ok, i will give that a go, and get back you